# How to use multiple selected option React

Tags: reactjs

There is an array of data that needs to be filtered when choosing a option in an selected. I will give demo data, but there can be many values.

If you filter by only one value, then the data is displayed correctly, but if you use several, then displayed incorrectly. Filter by date interval, unfortunately does not work

How to refactor so that filtering works correctly and takes into account several filters

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';

const items = [
    {
        id: "1",
        status: 100,
        event: "Open door",
        user: 'Mike',
        created_at:  '2020-09-05T12:31',
    },

    {
        id: "2",
        status: 200,
        event: "Call Answer",
        user: 'Vik',
        created_at:  '2020-09-04T18:32',
    },

    {
        id: "3",
        status: 300,
        event: "Call",
        user: 'Max',
        created_at:  '2020-08-03T18:30',
    },

    {
        id: "4",
        status: 400,
        event: "Missed call",
        user: 'Alex',
        created_at:  '2020-07-28T10:40',
    },
]

const Sample = () => {
    const [event, setEvent] = useState('All')
    const [user, setUser] = useState('All')
    const [dateBefore, setDateBefore] = useState(null)
    const [dateAfter, setDateAfter] = useState(null)


    let filter = []

    if (user !== 'All') {
        filter.push(items.filter((u) => u.user === user))
    }
    if (event !== 'All') {
        filter.push(items.filter((e) => e.event === event))
    }
    if (user && event === 'All') {
        filter.push(items)
    }

    if(dateAfter || dateBefore !== null) {
        filter.push(items.filter((e) => e.created_at > dateBefore && e.created_at < dateAfter))
    }


    const handleChangeUser = (event) => {
        setUser(event.target.value);

    };

    const handleChangeEvent = (event) => {
        setEvent(event.target.value);
    }


    let eventArr = items.map(e => {
        return e.event
    })
    eventArr.unshift('All')

    let userArr = items.map(e => {
        return e.user
    })
    userArr.unshift('All')

    return (
      <>
      <select style={{margin: '0 15px'}} value={event} onChange={handleChangeEvent}>

          { eventArr.map((name) => {
              return <option key={name} value={name}>
                  {name}
              </option>
          })}
      </select>
          <select style={{margin: '0 15px'}} value={user} onChange={handleChangeUser}>
              { userArr.map((name) => {
                  return <option key={name} value={name}>
                      {name}
                  </option>  })}
          </select>

          <DatePicker
            value={dateBefore}
            onChange={setDateBefore}
          />


          <DatePicker
            value={dateAfter}
            onChange={setDateAfter}
          />

          <div>
          {
              filter[0].map(userName => {
                  return(
                    <>
                      <div style={{marginTop: '10px'}}>{ userName.user + ' - ' + userName.event }</div>
                      <div style={{borderBottom: '2px solid black'}}>{userName.created_at}</div>
                  </>)
              })
          }
          </div>

      </>
    )

}

export default Sample;
```

Comment: wait so whats ur question

Comment: @cbracketdash, the question is how to fix it to work

Comment: ah ok i'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Looks like all your filters filter individually from the source `items` array and thus override any previous filtering. I.E. if you do filters in multiple passes, then each subsequent filter needs to filter the previous filter result, not add another filtered source.

## Solution

Create a filter callback function that looks at all your filter values simultaneously. This can be done in a single pass over the data using array::filter.

```
const filter = items.filter(
  (item) =>
    (user === "All" || item.user === user) &&
    (event === "All" || item.event === event) &&
    (!dateBefore ||
      item.created_at > DateTime.fromJSDate(dateBefore).toISO()) &&
    (!dateAfter || item.created_at < DateTime.fromJSDate(dateAfter).toISO())
);
```

`react-date-picker` also works with javascript Date objects, so the returned format doesn't match what is in your data. I resolved this by importing `Luxon` and created a new DateTime object *from* the javascript date format and convert it to ISO format.

[image: Edit how-to-use-multiple-selected-option-react]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

const items = [
  {
    id: "1",
    status: 100,
    event: "Open door",
    user: "Mike",
    created_at: "2020-09-05T12:31"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    status: 100,
    event: "Call Answer",
    user: "Mike",
    created_at: "2020-09-10T12:31"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    status: 200,
    event: "Call Answer",
    user: "Vik",
    created_at: "2020-09-04T18:32"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    status: 300,
    event: "Call",
    user: "Max",
    created_at: "2020-08-03T18:30"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    status: 400,
    event: "Missed call",
    user: "Alex",
    created_at: "2020-07-28T10:40"
  }
];

// Factor out duplicate select JSX code, more DRY
const Select = ({ options, value, onChange }) => (
  <select style={{ margin: "0 15px" }} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
    {options.map((name) => (
      <option key={name} value={name}>
        {name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

const Sample = () => {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState("All");
  const [user, setUser] = useState("All");
  const [dateBefore, setDateBefore] = useState(null);
  const [dateAfter, setDateAfter] = useState(null);

  const filter = items.filter(
    (item) =>
      (user === "All" || item.user === user) &&
      (event === "All" || item.event === event) &&
      (!dateBefore ||
        item.created_at > DateTime.fromJSDate(dateBefore).toISO()) &&
      (!dateAfter || item.created_at < DateTime.fromJSDate(dateAfter).toISO())
  );

  const handleChangeUser = (event) => {
    setUser(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeEvent = (event) => {
    setEvent(event.target.value);
  };

  // Mapping the data to options led to duplicate options,
  // reducing first into map removes duplicates and allows
  // for computing options in single pass. Values inserted
  // into map maintain insertion order.
  const [eventArr, userArr] = items.reduce(
    ([events, users], { event, user }) => [
      { ...events, [event]: event },
      { ...users, [user]: user }
    ],
    [
      {
        All: "All"
      },
      {
        All: "All"
      }
    ]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        onChange={handleChangeEvent}
        value={event}
        options={Object.values(eventArr)}
      />
      <Select
        onChange={handleChangeUser}
        value={user}
        options={Object.values(userArr)}
      />
      <DatePicker value={dateBefore} onChange={setDateBefore} />
      <DatePicker value={dateAfter} onChange={setDateAfter} />

      <div>
        {filter.map((userName) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
                {userName.user + " - " + userName.event}
              </div>
              <div style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid black" }}>
                {userName.created_at}
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```